# update an array nested in an object in an immutable way

Tags: reactjs, immutable.js

So I have this reducer that I would like to update

```
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';
const initialState = fromJS({
  searchParams: {
    limit: 100,
    page: 1,
    order_by: 'name',
    filters: {
      and_keywords : []
    }
  },
})
```

when the action is triggered I would like to push an object into the array of `and_keywords`. What I have done so far is this

```
case ADD_KEYWORDS:
return state
    .setIn(['searchParams', 'filters', 'and_keywords'], '123');
```

I also tried

```
case ADD_KEYWORDS:
return state
    .updateIn(['searchParams', 'filters', 'and_keywords'], arr => arr.push('123'))
```

basing from the documents in https://facebook.github.io, but I can't seem to make it work. No changes have been made after executing this command

Comment: Immutable objects don't modify in place, you have to reassign the thing you're modifying. So just add `state = ` to the start of your lines and it should work.

Comment: I already have `function homePageReducer(state = initialState, action) {` just did not include it as I only posted a snippet of my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `updateIn` version should work:

```
const Immutable = require('immutable')

const initialState = Immutable.fromJS({
  searchParams: {
    limit: 100,
    page: 1,
    order_by: 'name',
    filters: {
      and_keywords : []
    }
  },
})

const newState = initialState.updateIn(['searchParams', 'filters', 'and_keywords'], arr => arr.push('123'))

console.log(newState)
```

Your `setIn` version code should work as well with a small modification:

```
const Immutable = require('immutable')


const initialState = Immutable.fromJS({
  searchParams: {
    limit: 100,
    page: 1,
    order_by: 'name',
    filters: {
      and_keywords : []
    }
  },
})

const newState = initialState.setIn(['searchParams', 'filters', 'and_keywords'], initialState.getIn(['searchParams', 'filters', 'and_keywords']).push('123'))

console.log(newState)
```

Both should output:

```
Map { "searchParams": Map { "limit": 100, "page": 1, "order_by": "name", "filters": Map { "and_keywords": List [ "123" ] } } }
```

Comment: Yeah. It was another bug on my end that caused the issue. Accepted the answer still for reference for others to use. Thanks!